# what is this perl map call doing?

Tags: perl

```
join "", map { ( (0 .. 9, "a" .. "f")[rand(16)])} 1 .. 24;
```

I understand how map and join function works, but the thing bugs me is within the `{}`. It is an array with 16 elements and `rand()` gives a number referencing it. and I know `map` maps the number in  `1 .. 24` to what? the number return from referencing the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(list)[i]` just returns the i-th member of the list. So, you iterate over the list `1 .. 24`, mapping a random character to it by selecting a random member from the list of 16 chars.

You can get a similar output from

```
for (1.. 24) {
    print ( (0 .. 9, "a" .. "f")[rand 16] );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code just constructs a random 24 digit hex number.

The range `1..24` is just a throwaway iterator to define how many digits.  The code inside the [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) just selects a random element of the static array of hex digits.

I think the code is easier to read if we remove some of the extraneous spacing and parenthesis, but one can also achieve the same result using [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).  The following pieces of code are functionally identical:

```
print join("", map { (0..9, "a".."f")[rand 16] } 1..24), "\n";
print join("", map { sprintf "%x", int rand 16 } 1..24), "\n";
```